# Read csv by index size instead of withFirstRecordAsHeader using apache commons csv

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to read data in from a csv which looks like this:

```
id_number,last_name,first_name
123,Gibs,Walter
321,John,Chris
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
id_number,business_name
234,Abc Computers
417,Chris Inc
```

The row of commas represent a blank row (in Excel)

To be clear, here is an image of what the csv file looks like in excel:
[image]

```
public class CsvFileParser {

    public static void customerMethod() {
        BufferedReader fileReader = null;
        CSVParser csvParser = null;

        try {
            fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\prassuha\\JavaProjects\\gs-maven-master\\complete\\src\\main\\java\\hello\\customer.csv"));
            csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader,
                    CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());

            List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

            Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();

            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
                Customer customer = new Customer(
                        csvRecord.get("tracking_number"),
                        csvRecord.get("business_name"),
                );

                customers.add(customer);
            }

            for (Customer customer : customers) {
                System.out.println(customer);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Reading CSV Error!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileReader.close();
                csvParser.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Closing fileReader/csvParser Error!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void personalMethod() {
        BufferedReader fileReader = null;
        CSVParser csvParser = null;

        try {
            fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\prassuha\\JavaProjects\\gs-maven-master\\complete\\src\\main\\java\\hello\\customer2.csv"));
            csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader,
                    CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());

            List<Personal> personals = new ArrayList<Personal>();

            Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();

            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
                Personal personal = new Personal(
                        csvRecord.get("tracking_number"),
                        csvRecord.get("full_name"),
                );
                personals.add(personal);
            }

            for (Personal personal : personals) {
                System.out.println(personal);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Reading CSV Error!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileReader.close();
                csvParser.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Closing fileReader/csvParser Error!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        customerMethod();
        personalMethod();

    }
}
```

Currently, I am using withFirstRecordAsHeader() but I would like to check the size of the index then check for an empty row and then check size of index again. I'm not sure if that's the right approach- if there is a better way to read this in, please do share. Thanks!

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the entire file into memory, and split it on "blank" lines. Then parse each section separately.

The code below blindly assumes that the file has 2 sections, that first section is persons, and that second section is businesses. You might want to check those assumptions.

```
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.RFC4180
        .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
        .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
        .withTrim();

String fileName = "C:\\Users\\prassuha\\JavaProjects\\gs-maven-master\\complete\\src\\main\\java\\hello\\customer.csv";
String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String[] sections = input.split("(?m)^[,\\s]*\\R");

List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
try (CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(new StringReader(sections[0]), csvFormat)) {
    for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
        String id_number = csvRecord.get("id_number");
        if (id_number.isEmpty())
            break; // end of person part of CSV data
        persons.add(new Person(
                id_number,
                csvRecord.get("last_name"),
                csvRecord.get("first_name")));
    }
}

List<Business> businesses = new ArrayList<>();
try (CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(new StringReader(sections[1]), csvFormat)) {
    for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
        String id_number = csvRecord.get("id_number");
        if (id_number.isEmpty())
            break; // end of business part of CSV data
        businesses.add(new Business(
                id_number,
                csvRecord.get("business_name")));
    }
}
```